# NetBeans: change Java project's charset causes problems

Tags: java, database, character-encoding, connection

I like to ask if ever someone had same problem like me:

I started my project with encoding **UTF-8** (was default project's encoding). But since I'm from central Europe I decided **change encoding to Unicode**, because I didn't want use english alphabet only in in `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` windows.
My application also connects to database and after changing charset to Unicode connection suddenly didn't work saying

**`com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException:`
`Communications link failure due to underlying exception`**

Then I decided test it by changing charset back to UTF-8 and application was able connect again. I even compared my connection string characters positions if they are different in UTF-8 and Unicode, but they are same!

My question is: **How can I use East European alphabet (different charset from default UTF-8) in my project, when I want avoid connection problems?**

Comment: UTF-8 is Unicode supporting all characters required in Europe (and world wide). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 Maybe I do not understand your question?

Comment: UTF-8 is a Unicode encoding. You need understand the separation between the source file encoding from the data encoding in the database from the Java String encoding (UTF-16) and the transformation points between them (the Java compiler; the JDBC driver.)

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 doesn't cover all symbols in Slovak alphabet, that's why I decided change charset to UTF-16. After compilation some of specific Slovak letters looks different in UTF-8 as I expected.
Thing I don't understand is, that if i change charset to UTF-16 something change my connection string (and it looks like `jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_name?user=root&password=password`), which contains symbols from ASCII code table only and my program can't connect...
With latin2 and Windows-1250 i have no problem connect and use Central-European characters. Is it some kind of bug that Unicode cause such problems in NetBeans 7.2?